# Java mobile - Startup questions

Tags: java-me, mobile, sdk, startup

I am a J2SE Java developer, and i am currently trying to learn Java mobile development to create mobile applications. I have a couple of startup questions please :

1. Do i have to install JDK 6.0 or above, or only a J2ME SDK is quite enough ? (I don't know if the JDK includes J2ME API or not).
2. I have seen other Java mobile SDKs like [Metismo](http://www.metismo.com/) and [AlcheMo](http://www.innaworks.com/alchemo-java-me-j2me-to-brew-android-iphone-flash-windows-mobile-cross-compiler) that still allow me to write Java coded mobile applications, so are these better than the J2ME SDK or there are better options ?
3. I will use Eclipse Pulsar + J2ME SDK in development. Do i need anything else ? And is this developing environment suitable to write Java coded mobile applications to run on most mobile types or there are better options ?
4. For the Emulator does J2ME SDK include an emulator ? I have seen a Free emulator called  [Micro Emulator](http://www.microemu.org) so is this suitable, or there are better choices ?
5. If you have any advices / Tutorials for me before i start learning the language and coding my applications that would be very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest Netbeans better for mobile development. Even you can use Eclipse pulsar also. Netbeans already having [sun java SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html). you can download the Emulator from following sites,

- [Sprint SDK](http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/mobile_platforms/java_me/javame.jsp)
- [Sony Ericsson SDK](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads?cc=gb&lc=en)
- [Samsung SDK](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/)
- [Motorola SDK](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/sdks/)
- [Nokia SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/)

See these tutorials for j2me developing,

- [J2ME Tutorials](http://javalessons.com/cgi-bin/fun/java-tutorials-main.cgi?sub=jme&ses=ao789)
- [J2ME Coding example-1](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/)
- [J2ME Coding example-2](http://www.java-samples.com/j2me/)
- [J2ME Guide](http://j2mesalsa.com/j2meindex.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Should i use an emulator for every mobile brand to test my application on ? ... I hope you can help me with questions 1 & 2 to understand this.

Comment: Sun java toolkit enough for developing mobile application. But on testing environment you can test all mobile emulators.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Those tutorials are helpful.